# PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST and DECLARE

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have this sql query

```
"DECLARE @two INT SET @two=2 SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE id = @two;"
```

When processing a request through PDO, everything goes well, as long as I don't use

```
$this->result->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, \PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST);
```

due to the use of \PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST, it gives me an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY106]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Fetch type out of range

I definitely need to save FETCH_ORI_FIRST and in order for the query to work correctly, how can I do this?

Comment: From the man: (1) PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST (int)
Fetch the first row in the result set. Valid only for scrollable cursors. (2). To request a scrollable cursor for your PDOStatement object, you must set the PDO::ATTR_CURSOR attribute to PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL when you prepare the SQL statement with PDO::prepare().

Comment: (3) What makes you think that you  definitely need to "save" FETCH_ORI_FIRST? What exactly would work incorrectly otherwise?